# Unit Testing With Dependency Injection On controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'am tired to need to make fill the fields then login logout to do a simple test.

I search for xUnit and NUnit and i found several tuturials but. I want to test my modification to AccountController (asp.net core 2 mvc) i use a repository to put logic this repo.

The problem is how to make the arrange of test with all those dependency injection.

**Controller example.**

```
namespace Inside.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IUsersRepository _users;

    public AccountController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ILogger<AccountController> logger,
            IUsersRepository users
        )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;
        _users = users;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult RegisterFirstUser(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!_users.HasUsersInDB())
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SetupWebApp));
        }
        if (!_users.HasOnlySystemUser())
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login)); ;
        }
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now i don't know how to make a test to test this controller since have a lot of dependency injection. Specialy this two UserManager userManager, SignInManager signInManager

Sorry for the newbie question. :p

Comment: You replace the implementations for the injected services with mocks or stubs. What does `userManager` do within your controller? Generate a stub class that may return a forced (but expected) response e.g. `.HasUsersInDb()` will always return true.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq) to do this very easily. Say your controller has this signature:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

    public UsersController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

 ...
}
```

Then the test for this will look something like this (using Moq)

```
 [TestClass]
public class UsersControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IUserRepository> _userRepository;
    private Mock<ApplicationUserManager> _userManager;
    private Mock<ApplicationSignInManager> _signInManager;
    private UsersController _controller;
    private Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>> _userStore;
    private Mock<IAuthenticationManager> _authManager;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

        _userStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        _authManager = new Mock<IAuthenticationManager>();
        _userManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>(_userStore.Object);
        _signInManager = new Mock<ApplicationSignInManager>(_userManager.Object, _authManager.Object);

        _controller = new UsersController(_userManager.Object, _signInManager.Object, _userRepository.Object);

        //only do this if you want to use request object in your tests
        var returnUrl = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        request.Setup(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost:123"));
        var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext.Object, new RouteData());
        _controller.Url = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
    }
```